# Typescript generate another static member that is only computed once

Tags: typescript

I got a class that looks something like this

```
class Types {
    static type1 = {name: 'car', isCool: true};
    static type2 = {name: 'house', isCool: false};
    static type3 = {name: 'tree', isCool: true};
}
```

Now I'd like to get all the types that have the property 'isCool' set to true.
At the moment I am iterating through the class each time I need them.

I don't want to recompute it each time. Also this class will be in a separate file which I will import in multiple places and I only want to compute the array once.
How can this be done?

Comment: could you have a static array of types instead? then you could filter it

Comment: Yes, I thought about that, but I was wondering if there's a way to precompute a static member from other static members

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate it once and store it so that it won't be calculated again:

```
class Types {
    private static COOL_NAMES: string[];

    static type1 = { name: 'car', isCool: true };
    static type2 = { name: 'house', isCool: false };
    static type3 = { name: 'tree', isCool: true };

    static getCoolNames(): string[] {
        if (this.COOL_NAMES) {
            return this.COOL_NAMES;
        }

        this.COOL_NAMES = [];

        Object.keys(this).forEach(name => {
            if (this[name].isCool) {
                this.COOL_NAMES.push(name);
            }
        });

        return this.COOL_NAMES;
    }
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20class%20GTree%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20public%20static%20createNode(name%3A%20string)%3A%20GNode%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20GNodeImpl(name)%3B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aexport%20interface%20GNode%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20GNodeImpl%20implements%20GNode%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(public%20name%3A%20string)%20%7B%7D%0A%7D#src=function%20extend%3CT%3E(list%3A%20T%5B%5D)%3A%20T%5B%5D%20%26%20%7B%20swap(i1%3A%20number%2C%20i2%3A%20number)%3A%20void%20%7D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20(list%20as%20T%5B%5D%20%26%20%7B%20swap(i1%3A%20number%2C%20i2%3A%20number)%3A%20void%20%7D).swap%20%3D%20function%20(i1%3A%20number%2C%20i2%3A%20number)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20tmp%20%3D%20this%5Bi1%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this%5Bi1%5D%20%3D%20this%5Bi2%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this%5Bi2%5D%20%3D%20tmp%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20return%20list%20as%20T%5B%5D%20%26%20%7B%20swap(i1%3A%20number%2C%20i2%3A%20number)%3A%20void%20%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20list%20%3D%20extend(%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D)%3B%0Alist.swap(0%2C%202)%3B%0Aconsole.log(list)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5B3%2C%202%2C%201%5D#src=class%20CustomError%20extends%20Error%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(message%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20super(%60Lorem%20%22%24%7Bmessage%7D%22%20ipsum%20dolor.%60)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20this.name%20%3D%20'CustomError'%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0Athrow%20new%20CustomError('foo')%3B#src=class%20CustomError%20extends%20Error%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(message%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20super(%60Lorem%20%22%24%7Bmessage%7D%22%20ipsum%20dolor.%60)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20this.name%20%3D%20'CustomError'%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0Athrow%20new%20CustomError('foo')%3B#src=const%20IGNORE_FIELDS%20%3D%20new%20Map%3Cstring%2C%20string%5B%5D%3E()%3B%0Afunction%20JsonIgnore(cls%3A%20any%2C%20name%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20clsName%20%3D%20cls.constructor.name%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20list%3A%20string%5B%5D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(IGNORE_FIELDS.has(clsName))%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20list%20%3D%20IGNORE_FIELDS.get(clsName)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20list%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20IGNORE_FIELDS.set(clsName%2C%20list)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20list.push(name)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Base%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20toJson()%3A%20%7B%20%5Bname%3A%20string%5D%3A%20any%20%7D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20json%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20ignore%20%3D%20IGNORE_FIELDS.get(this.constructor.name)%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this).filter(name%20%3D%3E%20ignore.indexOf(name)%20%3C%200).forEach(name%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20json%5Bname%5D%20%3D%20this%5Bname%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20json%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20TblColabAdmin%20extends%20Base%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20snomatrcompl%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20nflativo%3A%20number%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%40JsonIgnore%0A%20%20%20%20ativo%3A%20boolean%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(snomatrcompl%3A%20string%2C%20nflativo%3A%20number%2C%20ativo%3A%20boolean)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super()%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.snomatrcompl%20%3D%20snomatrcompl%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.nflativo%20%3D%20nflativo%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.ativo%20%3D%20ativo%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20obj%20%3D%20new%20TblColabAdmin(%22str%22%2C%2043%2C%20true).toJson()%3B%0Aconsole.log(obj)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Object%20%7Bsnomatrcompl%3A%20%22few%22%2C%20nflativo%3A%2043%7D#src=type%20Level%20%3D%20%22DEBUG%22%20%7C%20%22INFO%22%20%7C%20%22WARN%22%20%7C%20%22ERROR%22%3B%0A%0Atype%20Loggers%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bname%3A%20string%5D%3A%20Logger%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20Logger%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20level%3A%20Level%3B%0A%20%20%20%20sub_loggers%3F%3A%20Loggers%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20json%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22loggers%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22logger1%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22logger1%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22level%22%3A%20%22DEBUG%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22sub_loggers%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22logger1.nested_logger1%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22logger1.nested_logger1%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22level%22%3A%20%22INFO%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22logger1.nested_logger2%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22logger1.nested_logger2%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22level%22%3A%20%22INFO%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22sub_loggers%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22logger1.nested_logger2.more_of_that%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22logger1.nested_logger2.more_of_that%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22level%22%3A%20%22INFO%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22logger2%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22logger2%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22level%22%3A%20%22WARN%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%20as%20%7B%20loggers%3A%20Loggers%20%7D%3B%0Alet%20loggers%3A%20Loggers%20%3D%20json%5B%22loggers%22%5D%3B#src=class%20Types%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20private%20static%20COOL_NAMES%3A%20string%5B%5D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20static%20type1%20%3D%20%7B%20name%3A%20'car'%2C%20isCool%3A%20true%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20static%20type2%20%3D%20%7B%20name%3A%20'house'%2C%20isCool%3A%20false%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20static%20type3%20%3D%20%7B%20name%3A%20'tree'%2C%20isCool%3A%20true%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20static%20getCoolNames()%3A%20string%5B%5D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(this.COOL_NAMES)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.COOL_NAMES%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.COOL_NAMES%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Object.keys(this).forEach(name%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(this%5Bname%5D.isCool)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.COOL_NAMES.push(name)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.COOL_NAMES%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D))

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it seems better to store the types in an array rather than separate members - it will make your life a lot easier and also seems more logical.
Second, you won't have to iterate over them with a `forEach` loop, you can use `filter`.
Lastly, You can store the calculation in a member so you could read it rather than running the calculation each time.

```
class Types {
    static types = [{name: 'car', isCool: true},
                    {name: 'house', isCool: false},
                    {name: 'tree', isCool: true}];

    public static coolName = this.getCoolNames();

    public static getCoolNames() {
        return this.types.filter((type) => type.isCool);
    }
}
```